# Ecosign API Integration with YII2?

Tags: php, yii2, echosign

I need to integrate echosign api to my yii2 advance application.

What is the folder structure for 3rd party API in YII2 ?

Where can i maintain api files?

What is the best practice for this?

Answer (score 1):

This is obvious that, the third party api goes to vendor directory by default.

> For the api,

dont know much but i think i have a reason to answer, that you have created, this can be placed anywhere as per the frequency of usage. If those apis are used from both **back-end** and **front-end**, then maintaining minimum api standard, we can place in common directory. Or, we can create a directory named **api** under application structure, and hence creating a **custom alias** for those apis that can be communicable.

Comment: Is api folder for 3rd party api's? I think that's for api service which we are going to provide any api serive. Am i right? @TNC

Comment: Yes, third party api's goes to vendor, only the api's that we are creating can be placed either by creating api directory or in already existing project bundle (backend/frontend) as per our requirement.

Comment: i need to integrated echosign api. Have you any idea about that?

Comment: I dont used that api yet, sorry.